# php file_get_content returing 401 on failed

Tags: php, api, http-headers, request, httprequest

I have web app and api and my login system works with api so it retruns: header status 200 if it success(username and password are correctly) otherwise it returns HTTP/1.0 401 Unauthorized and json message e.x: {success: 0 , "wrong username/password"} (tested with POSTMEN plugin in google chrome)

For e.x if i want to make a request:

```
$method = "login";
$data = array("user"=>"test", "pass"=>"test");
send_re($method, $data);
```

this is my function send_re

```
function send_re($method, $data){
$url = "api.location/".$api_method;
    $options = array(
      'http' => array(
        'method'  => 'POST',
        'content' =>  http_build_query($data),
        'header'=>  "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n" 

        )
    );

    $context  = stream_context_create( $options );
    $result = file_get_contents( $url, false, $context );

    return stripslashes( json_encode( $result) );
}
```

if my $data are correctly e.x username and password but if they are not I am not getting the error message but this:

```
A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Warning

Message: file_get_contents(http://85.10.229.108/home/login): failed to open stream: HTTP request       
 HTTP/1.0 401 Unauthorized

 Filename: libraries/api.php
```

Is there any way to escape this problem and get the message from api?

Comment: have you tried putting an `@` before `file_get_contents` to suppress warnings?

Comment: yes, it doesn't show the error with `@` but it doesn't return the response json e.x: `{success: 0 , "wrong username/password"}`

Comment: That is pretty much expected behaviour since HTTP 401 indicates an error and doesn´t return anything besides the error itself i guess. I assume you create the error via header() in the called script?

Comment: using `@` should indeed suppress the warning but it will also suppress reporting of more severe errors. Not the best practice.

Comment: @luk2302 yes the header 401 is created in the called script.

Comment: no, not the best, the best would be not to create an 401 and just check for the received json-data

Comment: i would suggest removing the 401 because it creates more problems than it solves. you already send the needed data in the json string, no need for an 401-header though.

Comment: well I haven't created the api so I need a solution or contact the api administrator to change it. :D

Comment: Isn't it a bit far-fetched to pop a 401 error for this? The 401 actually tells that your script is unauthorized to fetch the page.

Answer (score 0):

```
function send_re($method, $data){
$url = "api.location/".$api_method;
    $options = array(
      'http' => array(
        'method'  => 'POST',
        'content' =>  http_build_query($data),
        'header'=>  "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n",
        'ignore_errors' => true

        )
    );

    $context  = stream_context_create( $options );
    $result = file_get_contents( $url, false, $context );

    return stripslashes( json_encode( $result) );
}
```

Just add `'ignore_errors' => true` and it's do the trick.

reference: `http://php.net/manual/en/context.http.php`